# How to convert a string into Int collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, generics, collections

Below is my string.

```
var str = "1,2,3,4,5";

var strArr = str.split(","); // this gives me an array of type string

List<int> intCol = new List<int>(); //I want integer collection. Like
```

What I am doing is:-

```
foreach(var v in strArr)
{
     intCol.add(Convert.ToInt(v));
}
```

Is it right way to do it?

Comment: @sakbari: That duplicate isn't very close, it's not about a `,` separated list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var numbers = str.Split(',').Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToList();
```

But in such cases I would add some error handling in case the item could not be converted to an integer like this:

```
var strArr = str.Split(',')
    .Select(x =>
    {
        int num;
        if (int.TryParse(x, out num))
        {
            return num;
        }

        // Parse failed so return -1 or some other value or log it
        // or throw exception but then this whole operation will fail
        // so it is upto you and your needs to decide what to do in such
        // a case.
        return -1; 
    });
```

Note: `Convert.ToInt()` will throw a `FormatException` if the value cannot be converted. `TryParse` will not.

Comment: Got your point. The thing is you are using FluentApi but indirectly you are doing the same what I was doing using the foreach loop. Right??

Answer (score 4):

Well that's *a* way of doing it, certainly - but LINQ makes it a lot easier, as this is precisely the kind of thing it's designed for. You want a pipeline that:

- Splits the original string into substrings
- Converts each string into an integer
- Converts the resulting sequence into a list

That's simple:

```
List<int> integers = bigString.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToList();
```

The use of `int.Parse` as a method group is clean here, but if you're more comfortable with using lambda expressions, you can use

```
List<int> integers = bigString.Split(',').Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToList();
```